# Disabling screen minimization animation effect in iPhone:

Tags: iphone, animation, exit

Is it possible to disable the home screen minimize animation effect when user presses the home button on iPhone?. Or can we set our own custom image for minimize animation?

Regards ypk

Answer (score 1):

You cannot customize the minimization animation.

You can set an image to be shown full screen in `applicationWillTerminate:` but it wont last long as the application will quit soon after that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I 've tried to addSubview of a image to the window, but it did not work.

Comment: Oh, I think it would be getting buried under the other views that your application would have loaded. You can try using bringSubViewToFront to bring the added image view to front.

Comment: I tried this also, but it does not work. At the time applicationWillTerminate: delegate is called, the animation will be completed. Thats why I am not able to add views at that time.

Comment: I see. Then i dont think you can do anything about it. applicationWillTerminate is the only way to do something when the application quits.